# How to write .travis.yml if my project deps on python and nodejs?

Tags: travis-ci

My project includes some python codes and build with grunt.I write ***.travis.yml*** like:

```
language: node_js
before_install:
  - pip install Django
  - npm install -g grunt-cli
  - npm uninstall grunt # https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3958
node_js:
  - "0.10" 
python:
  - "2.7"
```

But that failed:
*

> OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.7.1.dist-info'

*

It seems like I cannot 'pip install' in a 'node_js' project.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `sudo`, pass the `--user` flag into `pip` (e.g., `pip install --user django`) to install the package in the home directory. This approach also works in Travis’ container-based infrastructure, which disallows `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of solved.A ***sudo*** must be prepend to '*pip install*'.

I guess '*npm install -g grunt-cli*' does not need ***sudo*** because it's a '***node_js***' project.Right?